# Overlay a CAMetalLayer view with alpha trasparency in SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, metal

I have a custom NSView which draws on its own CAMetalLayer. The rendered output includes an alpha channel, and has transparent and semi-transparent areas.

With AppKit views, this works as intended. When I wrap the view in a `NSViewRepresentable` SwiftUI view, though, it's as if the content of the alpha channel is ignored. What can be possibly missing?

I tried different pixel formats, including `rgb10a2Unorm` (the original one I was using) and `rgba16Float`, with no success.

Answer (score 2):

(Self-answer after I got it to work, at least on my development machine)

This was mostly correctly answered by [Transparent MTKView not blending properly with windows behind it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51354283/transparent-mtkview-not-blending-properly-with-windows-behind-it) but this question is about another specific case which triggers with SwiftUI. At this time, Apple still hasn't documented this very clearly, so additional information can still be useful.

In my case I had to:

1. Ensure that the I render premultiplied alpha, not "straight alpha" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Straight_versus_premultiplied). The value of the R, G, B channels needs to be rescaled by the alpha value. As the other answer points out:

   > any RGB component that is > the alpha component is undefined through the hardware’s blending

   Why is that the case, and why does it only matter in some cases? It could be a combination of factors (see point 3). This is especially hard to spot if you only have either fully opaque (alpha = 1.0) or fully transparent (alpha = 0.0) pixels.
2. Explicitly set `layer.isOpaque = false`. The default value for [`isOpaque` is documented to be `false`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410763-isopaque) but somehow going through SwiftUI and `NSViewRepresentable` makes it `true`, at least in some case. Little harm in setting it explicitly when needed.
3. Use `layer.pixelFormat = .rgba8Unorm` or `layer.pixelFormat = .rgba16Float`, either of which have different tradeoffs. This might be hardware-dependent, so I might refine this point as I test on more platforms. Contrary to the original answer, color space was not a relevant factor, but it might be on different systems.

Only with all three I could see transparency again.